# modal JDialog not updating

Tags: java, jdialog

I have a little problem with my modal JDialog. I want it to show while code is running in the background (downloading some Files) and updating the dialog, so the user can see the current status. Its downloading fine but not updating the dialog... Help me! I can't find my mistake. :c

Code Snippet:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parentFrame, "Element download...", true);
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setResizable(false);
dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
panel.setLayout(null);
dialog.add(panel);

final JLabel label = new JLabel("Starting download...");
label.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 20));
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
panel.add(label);

final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0, 118);
bar.setBounds(new Rectangle(20, 0, 300, 80));
panel.add(bar);

dialog.pack();
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parentFrame);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Executin some code (that works fine)
                bar.setValue(value);  
                label.setText(text);
                System.out.println(text);
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Where is the code that downloads the files?  All of the code in your Thread is executed on the Event Dispatch thread.  Also, you should make the JDialog visible before you start the Thread.

Comment: Why would you need the code? I cutted it out because its very long. If I set the the JDialog visible before executing the thread, the thread wont be executed until the dialog is close, because of the JDialog blocking any other actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Thread and SwingUtilities.invokeLater() incorrectly.

The point of a Thread is to execute a long running task (your file download) in a separate thread so you don't block the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`.

The point of SwingUtilities.invokeLater() is to add code to the EDT.

So in your case you are adding the file download code to the EDT, which means the GUI can't respond to events or repaint itself until all the file downloads are complete.

You want the Thread to run the code for the download and then as each file is finished downloading you create a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) to update the bar and label.

The easiest way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker` and `publish()` the results as they become available.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and working examples of a `SwingWorker`.